# MATLAB: More efficient code for withincluster dissimilarity function

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I'm quite new to Matlab and this is my code for Within cluster dissimilarity in a given dataset.

This code is really inefficient and my computer almost crashed for running this on `30x4 dataset`.

Can anyone help me with a better version of this?

Here is my code which i used.

```
function [W] = WIC( X , IDX , N , C )


W = zeros( N , 1 );
kclas = unique(IDX);
count = histc( IDX(:) , kclas );

for i =1:N
    for j=1:length(X)
       while IDX(j)==i
          W = sum( ( X(j,:) - C(i,:) ).^2 );
       end
    end
end

 W = W .* count;
end
```

Comment: Share with us the calling script too? At least the sizes of inputs to the function?

Comment: First I used K-means on 20x3 numerical matrix keeping the no. of clusters to 2.

Comment: Then I used the IDX( indexing array) and C (cluster Centroids) which kmeans returns as input arguments to WIC

Comment: Your code is wrong, since W is overwritten at every loop step.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like, for each cluster, to calculate the (average?) sum of squared Euclidean distances from the cluster center.

Aside from assigning the outputs to elements of `W` (`W(i)=...`), not having an infinite loop (the `while` loop will either never run or never finish), you may want to look into vectorization. Fortunately, there are nice functions such as `accumarray`

```
%// IDX: cluster index
%// X: array of data points
%// C: cluster centers
%// N: number of clusters

totalSumOfSquares = accumarray(IDX,(1:N)',[],...
   @(id) sum(sum( bsxfun( @minus, X, C(id,:) ).^2,2),1));
```

If you want the average squared distance, replace the first `sum` with `mean`.

Answer (score 0):

Why?

This measure is a largely useless statistic; it only makes sense within k-means. And then it is best computed by just *summing the squared deviations* as you are assigning objects, instead of recomputing it at the end *again*.